# Playing mp3 stream from winamp server

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, audio-streaming, winamp

I am developing an app that requires playing a web radio stream. I have been reading online on how to do that and it seems that there are many ways like the AVAudioplayer, the Audio File Stream services and the Audio Streamer project from Matt Gallagher. Since i just started reading about it maybe some of them are the same, but I was wondering whats the best way to do this?

Also, is there any way to get the current song name from the winamp server stream?

Thanks,
Yannis